# Virtual Box - Losing IP in bridged network

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, bridging

I have an Ubuntu VM in which I deployed images and the rootfs for my U-Boot. In the VirtualBox (Version 5.0.2) Settings I have adjusted a *Bridged Adapter*. In this image you can see my set-up:
[image: Set up]

When I give the VM an IP with

```
sudo ifconfig eth1 192.168.99.1
```

I can ping the VM with U-Boot.  However `eth1` interface loses the IP very quickly again and I found no solutions how to prevent this.

I read that this has to do with the ARP-protocol and can't be disabled. Can you help me with possible configurations for how I can access a VM on a host from an board with U-Boot?

PS: The board and the host is only connected through a LAN cable. I read somewhere that a switch between would resolve the losing of the IP. I tried this but nothing seemed to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now could eventually receive an IP, which I don't lose. Everyone who has the same issue, namely losing IP after a short time in bridged network can use this solution, too `[My Ubuntu is 14.04 LTS]`.

In the host system nothing has been changed. I still use a *Bridged Adapter* in Virtual Box.

**1. Set up a [DHCP Server](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/isc-dhcpd)*:**

```
sudo apt-get install isc-dhcp-server
```

**2. Edit the configuration file for the DHCP daemon:**
    `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`:

```
cat >> /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf << EOF
subnet 192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        interface eth1;
        range 192.168.2.10 192.168.2.40;
        option domain-name-servers 192.168.2.1;
        option broadcast-address 192.168.2.255;
        option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
        option routers 192.168.2.1;
}
EOF
```

(The parameters can adapted on individual needs of course.)

**3. Start the DHCP-Server:**

```
sudo /etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server start
```

**4. Wait for your IP:**

```
ifconfig eth1 | grep "inet addr"
```

There might be problems with getting an IP. Disabling the ethernet interface with the command `ip link set eth0 down` and rebooting and starting the DHCP-Server again might help with this problem.

Take a loo into `/var/log/syslog` in the case you should encounter errors:

```
cat /var/log/syslog
```

---

*The Guide is in German, however on the bottom of the side there are links to English sites.